# Infinite recusion when returning the a "list.append" in python3

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, recursion

I am making a code that returns a list of all the suffixes of a word. For example, if I enter

```
INPUT : "abcdefg" I expect the following output :

OUTPUT : ['abcdefg',·'bcdefg',·'cdefg',·'defg',·'efg',·'fg',·'g', '']
```

I could write this code pretty easily making it iterative, but I need to use recursion, so I wrote the following program :

```
def delete_head(my_string):
    my_list = list(my_string)
    my_list = my_list.pop(0)
    return my_list

def list_to_string(my_list):
    my_string = "".join(my_list)
    return my_string

def suffixes(x):
    list_suffixes = [x] #does this makes sense ?
    
    without_head = delete_head(x)
    without_head = list_to_string(without_head)
    
    #base cases
    if without_head == "" :
        return list_suffixes.append("''")

    #recursive step
    else :
        return list_suffixes.append(suffixes(without_head))

        
def main():
    x = input()
    
    print( suffixes(x) )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the code above, I have 2 auxiliary functions that are used, respectively to :

•delete the first element of a string by converting it to a list;
•convert a list into a string

Now, taking a look at the `suffixes` function, in the first line I add to my `list_suffixes` the word itself, since the word is its own suffix, but I fear this messes up the others recursive calls, since this value may be overwritten.

In the base case, if the word `x` is empty, I simply want an empty string to be added into the `list_suffixes`, otherwise, I want the next suffix to be added into the list.

I guess the way I did this, doesn't make much sense, since this generate an "infinite recursion", so, if anyone help me, it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

One of the useful things about structuring your program into individual functions is that you can test them separately, and make sure they do what you intended.

In this case, try running `delete_head("hello")` and you'll see that rather than returning a list *without* the head, it returns *the head itself*. That's because `pop()` doesn't return a new list, it changes the original list, and returns the item it removed. So you want this - note the change in the second line:

```
def delete_head(my_string):
    my_list = list(my_string)
    my_list.pop(0)
    return my_list
```

There is actually a more "pythonic" way to remove the start of a string (or list) using a "slice":

```
def delete_head(my_string)
    return my_string[1:]
```

The `[1:]` means "from character (or item) 1, up to the end of the string (or list)". You can also specify other slices like `[2:5]`, `[:3]`, or `[-1:]` (negative numbers mean count back from the end)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what happens when your main function runs:

1. User gives input, say "abcdefg"
2. suffixes is called and list_suffixes is set to ["abcdefg"]
3. delete_head is called on "abcdefg" and returns "a" after popping the first element from "abcdefg". without_head is set to "a".
4. list_to_string is called on "a" and returns "a". without_head is set to "a".
5. without_head is "a", not "", so we enter the else statement.
6. suffixes is called on without_head and in the new instance, list_suffixes is set to ["a"]
7. delete_head is called on "a" and returns "a" after popping the first (and only element) from "a". without_head is set to "a".
8. Go the step 4.

Hopefully you can see why this gives you infinite recursion.

If you make the change in IMSoP's answer, your infinite recursion will be fixed but you will get None being returned rather than your expected result. The program will actually execute as expected. You can see this by adding

```
print(my_string)
```

to the list_to_string functionm or at some other equivalent place. You will see the program print out

```
abcdefg
bcdefg
cdefg
defg
efg
fg
g
```

as expected. The issue happens when you go to return because list.append always returns None.

If you want to get the desired result after making IMSop's change (shown below for completeness):

```
def delete_head(my_string):
    my_list = list(my_string)
    my_list.pop(0)
    return my_list
```

you should use list concatenation and return the full list. Here's an example of how to do that:

simply change

```
if without_head == "" :
        return list_suffixes.append("''")

    #recursive step
    else :
        return list_suffixes.append(suffixes(without_head))
```

to:

```
if without_head == "" :
    return ['']

#recursive step
else :
    list_suffixes += suffixes(without_head)

return list_suffixes
```

The difference here is that rather than returning the result of append (which is always None), we return a list, and at every step concatenate the new list from the recursive call with the old list using python's += notation.

Also, you can make your program simpler by removing changing

```
def delete_head(my_string):
    my_list = list(my_string)
    my_list.pop(0)
    return my_list
```

to

```
def delete_head(my_string):
    return my_string[1:]
```

This will give you the same result using slicing. In python, the index [x:] returns all elements after (and including) x. Using this [1:] as the index will return all elements except for the 0th element. With this change, list_to_string becomes redundant and its call can be removed. The final script would be:

```
def delete_head(my_string):
    return my_string[1:]

def suffixes(x):
    list_suffixes = [x] #does this makes sense ?
    
    without_head = delete_head(x)
    #base cases
    if without_head == "" :
        return ['']
    #recursive step
    else :
        list_suffixes += suffixes(without_head)
    return list_suffixes
def main():
    x = input()
    
    print( suffixes(x) )
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you ! Your explanation was pretty good. I just didn't understand why the function "suffixes" was returning None, although you fixed the "delete_head" function, if you could explain me this part I would be much grateful

Comment: I just noted a very funny behavior, the program doesn't append the penultimate item. How could we solve that ?

Comment: @HaveMercy sorry I didn’t get back to this sooner. The function “suffixes” was returning none because of the statement “return list_suffixes.append(…)”.  The append function of a list is a function that modified the list my adding the requested value to the end of the list, then it returns None to the caller. So the return statement calls the append function, the append function resolved to none, and suffixes returns that none that it gets back from the append function

Comment: @HaveMercy that is very strange. Let me see if I can replicate it and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of recursion to generate the required output:

```py
def suffixes(x):
    yield x
    if x:
        yield from suffixes(x[1:])

s = "abcdefg"
print(list(suffixes(s)))
```

Prints:

```
['abcdefg', 'bcdefg', 'cdefg', 'defg', 'efg', 'fg', 'g', '']
```

Comment: While this is a useful implementation, there's not a lot of explanation of how it works. The context of the question seems to be someone who's just learning the language, so a simpler version, or more details on what's going on, would probably be more useful to them.